# why it's showing error??help me out

Tags: blockchain-fork

```js
const Chocolate = artifacts.require("Chocolate");
contract("Chocolate", (accounts) => {
  before(async () => {
    instance = await Chocolate.deployed()
  })
  it('ensure the starting balance of chocolate machine is 500', async () => {
    let balance = await instance.getBalanceChocolate();
    assert.equal(balance, 500, 'initial balance should be 500 chocolate')
  });
  it('ensure balance of chocolate can be updated', async () => {
    await instance.reStock(100)
    let balance = await instance.getBalanceChocolate();
    assert.equal(balance, 600, 'updated balance should be 600 chocolate after restocking')
  });
  it('ensure the purchase can be well performed', async () => {
    await instance.purchase(1, { from: accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei("3", 'ether') })
    let balance = await instance.getBalanceChocolate();
    assert.equal(balance, 499, "The balance should be 499 after purchasing")
});
```

test truffle :

✔ ensure the starting balance of chocolate machine is 500 (38ms)
✔ ensure balance of chocolate can be updated (223ms)
1) ensure the purchase can be well performed #1
> No events were emitted

2 passing (543ms)
1 failing

1. Contract: Chocolate
   ensure the purchase can be well performed:
   AssertionError: The balance should be 499 after purchasing: expected <BN: 257> to equal 499
   at Context. (test\Chocolate.js:18:12)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, we have no idea why your purchase() function is not passing its test. Somehow after purchasing 1 chocolate, your contract loses 343 chocolates.